# I can't remove all the paragraphs in the page via JavaScript

Tags: dom, iteration, addeventlistener, removechild, getelementsbytagname

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>An HTML5 Document</title>
<p>1
<p>2
<p>3
<p>4
<p>5
<p>6
<p>7
<p>8
<p>9
<p>10
<p>11
<p>12
<script>
    // When the document is clicked, codes below should remove all the paragraphs in the page.
    // There are 12 paragraphs in the page, but codes below can just remove 6 of them.
    document.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var i, allParagraphElements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
        console.log('allParagraphElements.length: ' + allParagraphElements.length);
        for (i = 0; i < allParagraphElements.length; i += 1) {
            console.log('i: ' + i);
            allParagraphElements[i].parentNode.removeChild(allParagraphElements[i]);
        }
    }, false);
</script>
```

See codes on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7NmRh

How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Fiddles are fine, but users should not have to click out just to see the fundamentals of your code. Please post the code as part of the question wherever possible.

Comment: what does `<p>1` mean? Where does the `p` tag end?

Comment: @d4rkpr1nc3: Closing `</p>` tags are optional. You can't have nested `<p>` elements. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You iterate from top to bottom:

**Iteration one:**
twelve paragraphs, index = 0

paragraph at index 0 is deleted and paragraph 1 is now at index 0

**Second iteration:**
Eleven paragraphs, index = 1

paragraph at index  1 is deleted and paragraph 2 is now at index 1

---

You see what's going wrong? You only delete half of the paragraphs

Iterate the other way around and all the paragraphs are deleted

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7NmRh/2/)

Answer (score 3):

`.getElementsByTagName` returns a live nodelist which is automatically updated as you make changes to the underlying subtree it represents. Basically, when you remove elements the `.length` is changed as well and the loop will end "prematurely".

You could use `.querySelectorAll` to get a static nodelist instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/7NmRh/1/

```
allParagraphElements = document.querySelectorAll('p');
```

---

​
You can also convert the nodelist to an array, which behaves like a static nodelist as well:

```
allParagraphElements = [].slice.call( document.getElementsByTagName('p') );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7NmRh/4/

Comment: Some versions of IE dont know about `addEventListener`. You should take that into consideration

Comment: @d4rkpr1nc3 that's not my code, it's the OP's code. I am not here to review the irrelevant parts of the OP's code, unless they are really wrong :P