# why javascript for loop doesn't work for DOM method

Tags: javascript

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <script>
       window.onload = function(){

         var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

         for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){

           document.body.removeChild(input[i]);

         }

       }
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input></input>
   <input></input>
    <input></input>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expected the input element is all removed by using the `removeChild` method in the for loop, but it seems like the 3rd input element(index of 2) didn't get removed.

Why?

Comment: duplicate of [javascript trying to remove all things with certain tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889720/javascript-trying-to-remove-all-things-with-certain-tags) or [I can't remove all the paragraphs in the page via JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722760/i-cant-remove-all-the-paragraphs-in-the-page-via-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` is a [live node collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#A_.22live.22_collection) (either a `NodeList` or an `HTMLCollection`). By removing the element you are modifying the collection. It's like removing from or adding to an array while iterating over it.

You can either convert the collection to an array first (the array will not change when you add or remove nodes):

```
var input = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("input"));
```

or iterate over the collection in reverse order:

```
for(var i = input.length - 1; i > -1; i--)
```

---

> but it seems like the 3rd input element(index of 2) didn't get removed. Why?

Let's go through the loop (the bullet points are iterations):

1. `input.length = 3`, `i = 0`. The first input element is removed.
2. `input.length = 2`, `i = 1`. The *originally third* input element is removed.
3. `input.length = 1`, `i = 2`. Loop stops because condition is not fulfilled.

The second `input` element was not removed from the document, it was skipped. At the second iteration, the second element was at index `0` since the first element was removed.

Comment: If you're curious, the reason he uses `[].slice.call` is because since NodeList is like an array, but not quite an array, it doesn't have a `slice` method. However, functions can be called in the context of other objects by using their `.call` method. Just figured that might look weird to some coders.

Comment: is it possible that i store input.length in a variable before the loop start then just assign the pre-defined variable into the for loop condition?

Comment: @dramasea: No, you would still skip elements because the data structure changes. The change of the `length` is not the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's crazy but you can solve it backwards: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ztMDP/)

```
window.onload = function(){
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i = input.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        document.body.removeChild(input.item(i));
    }
}
```

[my account fiddle too](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/sFy9z/)

Answer (score 0):

Each time your loop executes, it adds 1 to i, and deletes a element from the input array. on the third iteration it tries to delete index 2 in in a collection that only contains 1 item.

changing to a while would 'fix' this

```
    while( input.length > 0 ){
        document.body.removeChild(input[0]);
   }
```